# What does the head of smarty cache files mean?

Tags: caching, smarty

```
132
a:4:{s:8:"template";a:1:{s:10:"index.html";b:1;}s:9:"timestamp";i:1256373019;s:7:"expires";i:1256373079;s:13:"cache_serials";a:0:{}}<body>
 php<br >
  java<br >
  c++<br >

</body>
```

Can someone explain this part:

```
132
    a:4:{s:8:"template";a:1:{s:10:"index.html";b:1;}s:9:"timestamp";i:1256373019;s:7:"expires";i:1256373079;s:13:"cache_serials";a:0:{}}
```

Comment: Do you need to know the internal workings of Smarty cache files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a serialized version of an PHP array:

```
<?php
$serialized = 'a:4:{s:8:"template";a:1:{s:10:"index.html";b:1;}s:9:"timestamp";i:1256373019;s:7:"expires";i:1256373079;s:13:"cache_serials";a:0:{}}';
$unserialized = unserialize($serialized);
print_r($unserialized);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
[template] => Array
    (
        [index.html] => 1
    )

[timestamp] => 1256373019
[expires] => 1256373079
[cache_serials] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Smarty, but that looks like something similar to [Bencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencoding), which is where you encode things like strings and arrays by specifying their lengths first. This avoids having to delimit such things with "special characters" (such as quotes) which then need to be "escaped" if they appear in the real string.

- `132` is the length of the encoded string.
- `a:4:` looks like it's introducing an associative array (dictionary) with 4 items.
- `s:8:"template"` seems to be a string of length 8, with the value "template". In this case, it is the key of the first item in the dictionary.
- The value of that item is, in this case, another dictionary which just maps the key "index.html" to the integer value 1.
- ...And I think you can work out the rest.